# Wrong Exception catched when up-casting

Tags: java, exception

My problem is about wrong catched exception when up-casting. I have no idea what is incorrect...

I create three `Exception`s which looks like this :

```
class A extends Exception{
    public void f() throws A{
        System.out.println("Exception from A()");
        throw new A();
    }
    public void g() throws A{
        System.out.println("Exception from A()");
        throw new A();
    }
}
class B extends A{
    @Override
    public void f() throws B{
        System.out.println("Exception from B()");
        throw new B();
    }
}
class C extends B{
    @Override
    public void f() throws C{
        System.out.println("Exception from C()");
        throw new C();
    }
}
```

...and I want create `C` object and cast this object to `A` and catch `A` exception. My main looks like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            C obj = new C();
            ((A)obj).f(); // cast object C --> A....  Why it isn't work ?!
                            // should catch exception A not C !!!
                            // problem is when f() method is overrided by subclass

//            ((A)obj).g(); // working CORRECT when use other method...

//           A obj2 = (A) obj; // I try other casting type
//           obj2.g(); //method g() from exception A - work CORRECT, exception A catched...

        } catch (C e) { //third in hierarchy
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        } catch (B e) { //second..
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        } catch (A e) { //base
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
```

At the output netbeans returns info :

```
Exception from C()
exceptions.C
    at exceptions.C.f(HierarchyExceptions.java:24)
    at exceptions.HierarchyExceptions.main(HierarchyExceptions.java:32)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I have no idea why it returns wrong exception... I try comment

```
            //} catch (C e) { //third in hierarchy
            //    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            //} catch (B e) { //second..
            //    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            } catch (A e) { //base
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
```

...but it returns C exception too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In classes `B` and `C` you are effectively overriding the definition of the `f()` method from class `A`.**

```
C obj = new C();
((A)obj).f(); // cast object C --> A....  Why it isn't work ?!
              // should catch exception A not C !!!
              // problem is when f() method is overrided by subclass
```

This code will create an instance of class `C` and store it into local variable of type `A`. Once you are calling the `f()` method it will be executed on the real instance which is `C`, not `A` (the rules of overriding in Java).

Comment: Overriding f() method is intentional, but when I up-casting I should get exceptions from casting object not which was creating refenrece before...

Comment: So it's impossible to use exceptions from A superclass by up-casting? NetBeans shows me that i use f() method from A so I was surprised, NetBeans tells me this (look at the screenshoot) https://www.dropbox.com/s/9vzrops8cqwvaif/Zrzut%20ekranu%202015-07-23%2013.18.56.png?dl=0

Comment: Aww okey now I understand ! :) I think that it's possible to call method which was overrided (method from superclass) THANKS for answer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

it is the correct behaviour, cast or not the correct implementation is invoked: This is the concept of `Dynamic method dispatch`